# Can this greedy algorithm be more efficient?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, greedy

I'm studying for my exam coming up and I am practicing a problem that wants me to implement a greedy algorithm.

I am given an unsorted array of different weights where 0 < weight_i for all i. I have to place all of them such that I use the least number of piles. I can **not** place two weights in a pile where the one on top is greater than the one below. I also have to respect the ordering of the weights, so they must be placed in order. There is no height limit for the pile.

An example: If I have the weights {53, 21, 40, 10, 18} I cannot place 40 above 21 because the pile must be in descending order, and I cannot place 21 above 40 because that does not respect the order. An optimal solution would have pile 1: 53, 21, 10 and pile 2: 40 18

My general solution is iterate through the array and always pick the first pile the weight is allowed to go. I believe this would give me an optimal solution (although I haven't proved it yet). I could not find a counter example to this. But this would be O(n^2) because worst case I have to iterate through every element and every pile (I think)

My question is, is there a way to get this down to O(n) or O(nlogn)? If there is I'm just not seeing it and need some help.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use greedy

Comment: "so they must be placed in order" - can you traverse through the array more than one time?

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm will give a correct result.

Now note the following: when visiting the piles in order and stopping at the first one where the next value can be stacked, you will always have a situation where the stacks are ordered by their current top (last) value, in ascending order.

You can use this property to avoid an iteration of the piles from "left to right". Instead use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), among the piles, to find that first pile that can take the next value.

This will give you a *O(nlogn)* time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, the problem you describe is equivalent to *computing the length of the longest increasing subsequence*. There's a neat little greedy idea as to why.

Consider the longest increasing subsequence (LIS) of the array. Because the elements are ascending in index and also ascending in value, they must all be in different piles. As a result the minimum number of piles needed is equal to the number of elements in the LIS.

LIS is easily solvable in `O(NlogN)` using dynamic programming and a binary search.

Note that the algorithm you describe does the same thing as the algorithm below - it finds the first pile you can put the item on (with binary search), or it creates a new pile, so this serves as a "proof" of correctness for your algorithm and a way to reduce your complexity.

Let `dp[i]` be equal to the minimum value element at the end of an increasing subsequence of length `(i + 1)`. To reframe it in terms of your question, `dp[i]` would also be equal to the weight of the stone on the `ith` pile.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def lengthOfLIS(nums):

    arr = []

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        idx = bisect_left(arr, nums[i])
        if idx == len(arr):
            arr.append(nums[i])
        else:
            arr[idx] = nums[i]
    return len(arr)
```

Comment: Can you explain how that would serve as a proof? I'm currently trying to prove this solution is optimal, but I really don't understand how. I need any hint I can get.

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest the optimal number of piles _can't be fewer_ than the length of the LIS. Each element in the LIS has to be in a different pile. Think about it - LIS is a sequence such that for each element if `i < j` (the index) then `arr[i] < arr[j]` (the value). Obviously if a pile has `i`, then it can't also have `j`, because `j` comes after `i` and it must be on top, but `arr[j] > arr[i]` so you can't place it on top - it has to be in a different pile. So we establish that each element in the LIS has to be in a different pile, and thus creates our lower bound.

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest are you familiar with subsequences / longest increasing subsequence? I'm trying to do my best to help you understand, and I'd like to just gauge how detailed I should be - algorithms are hard :)

Comment: How do we prove that while the optimal solution can't have less than the LIS, it also cannot have more?

Comment: @גלעדברקן because the greedy solution OP described is equivalent to LIS, and because it indeed does build each pile, having that many piles is possible. When we build the LIS array, `dp[i]` is equal to the weight of the stone on the `ith` pile. When we update `dp`, we are equivalently placing a stone on that pile. Since we literally build the minimal solution, we by default prove that it also exists. The optimal solution can't be greater because the solution we built exists, so the optimal can't be greater, only less. But the solution we built also sets a lower bound.

Comment: I am not familiar with the longest increasing subsequence problem, but that explanation seems to make sense to me.

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest imagine selecting some elements from the array and covering the rest up such that the elements still shown form an increasing sequence. The LIS is the longest such sequence. Since the two problems are equivalent, it's length is also the minimum number of piles